# Asking employer for another interview to discuss working conditions

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

My situation is that I am offered a job position after one interview and a coding task. In the first interview, I didn't asked much questions because I was not sure if it will lead to anything.

Now I have many questions regarding work condition, and other benefits that I want to ask them. I am thinking of asking them for another skype call so I can discuss all my questions with them before accepting any offer.

My question is, is it okay to ask for another interview as a candidate to just ask your questions. Or should I stick to E-Mail for those questions.

Answer (score 4):

Just call the HR/Manager and talk through things to be sure you are good with the offer as written.  Once they offer to you they are expecting/hoping you a part of the company team, so will be happy to answer questions if that means you sign the line and start working for them.  You don't need an official "Interview" just call and ask questions as needed until you are good.

P.S. In the future just ask your questions st the end of the interview, it will only communicate that you really want to work for them and that you are very thorough...

Answer (score 1):

It is very normal and a good thing to ask any number of questions now that you have an offer in hand! In fact, this is the best time to ask some of those tricky questions about working conditions and expectations.

Is your current offer in writing? If not, this is the first thing to ask for. That may answer some of your questions.

I would send an email to whoever communicated the offer. List your questions and indicate that the answers are important to you as you evaluate the offer. This is the time when you have quite a bit of power. The employer has been through their hiring process and decided you are the best fit. They do not want to have go through that process again if possible. If certain issues would cause you to turn down the job, be honest about that. The employer does not want an unhappy employee.